# How to write an extension method for a razor page

Tags: c#, razor, extension-methods

I want to create an extension method that I can reference in a Razor page and includes both IHTmlHelper and IViewComponentHelper within it's context.

**Background**

In a Razor page, you can call code like this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(...)
```

as well as:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync(...)
```

**The goal**

I want to create a Razor page extension method so we could write code like:

```
@await Custom.DoThis(...)
```

I don't want to extend HtmlHelper or ComponentHelper, but I do want them to be available within my context.

I've gone through the Razor code and can't see any way to extend the razor page itself.

Comment: What is `Custom` in this context? What will your `DoThis` method do? Why are you opposed to creating an extension method for `IHtmlHelper`? (Because that's exactly what `IHtmlHelper` is meant for).

Comment: Write an ExtensionMethod-class and include the namespace in your view... where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is including both ComponentHelper and HTMLHelper in the same extension without having to include one of them as an argument.

Comment: should I rename my title, "How to write an extension method that attaches to the razor page instance" or how would you say that?